# scheduledExecutorService.awaitTermination blocks when shutdown is not called

Tags: java, java-8, jvm-hotspot

Hello I run unit tests.

I expect the code to block on awaitTermination until the underlying tasks are finished.

But i have code that blocks to long on debian java build 1.8.0_131-b11
,it does not block to long on osx java build 1.8.0_144-b01

```
@PreDestroy
    public void cleanUp(){
        log.info("trying to shutdown the FileWatcher gracefully, this can block the shutdown until the tasks are finished");
        try {
            scheduledExecutorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
        log.info("FileWatcher shutdown");
    }
```

On debian the code blocks for 1 hour. On osx it blocks until the
underlying tasks are finished.

the code does not block longer then needed when scheduledExecutorService.shutdown(); is called before the try clause. In this case the behaviour seems to be the same on osx and debian.

I would expect the blocking to stop when the registered tasks are finished. Is this a bug in the jvm? Is it wrong to not call shutdown()?

Comment: The pool shouldn't shutdown by itself. If you don't shutdown a pool, you can still submit new tasks later on. If you're finished with the pool, you need to call `shutdown()`. This seems like a bug with `1.8.0_131`.

Comment: @Kayaman interesting... do you have an actual reference for that? thx

Comment: Err, bug on the `144` of course. It should block forever (or until timeout), since its waiting for termination and termination is done explicitly with `shutDown()`.

Comment: As the documentation for [awaitTermination()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) says: `Blocks until all tasks have completed execution **after a shutdown request**, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted, whichever happens first.`.

Comment: Can't seem to find a related bug report though.

Comment: Either, `shutdown()` or `shutdownNow()`, must be called, otherwise, waiting the specified time is exactly the expected behavior. There is the theoretical scenario that the executor service gets garbage collected when no pending task exists, the core pool size is zero, all worker threads have been terminated due to timeout and no other reference exists. It would further require quiet aggressive optimizations, as it has to inline `awaitTermination` and eliminate all field access (it only reads `final` fields). I could not produce such a behavior, but I don’t have OS X+Java8u144b01…

Comment: Hi @tomdp could you please provide complete test case. Let me try to reproduce and create an issue on your bahalf :)